# Unable to search against database correctly with &#39;

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, utf-8, character-encoding

I am having trouble searching against a MySQL database. The database collation is `utf8_general_ci`, with the table collation as `latin1_swedish_ci`. My problem is this:

A user entry is stored as (fake name for privacy) `T&#39;quila Smith`, with the real name being `T'quila Smith`.

My web application needs to be able to correctly search for that user by name, but with the name being searched as `T'quila`, rather than `T&#39;quila`. I have tried using `$student_name = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $student_name);`, which (when tested with echo) prints out `T&#39;quila` like it should. However, the database cannot find this user in the database with that search.

Can anyone offer some assistance with this? I have been at a loss to what could be doing this. I have looked into character sets (which I think might be the issue), but I can't seem to get this working. Many thanks to whoever can help me!

Comment: You say Mr. Smith's name is stored in the table in entitized form (with &#39; rather than apostrophe).  How do you know that?  What happens if you search `WHERE NAME LIKE '%39%'` ?  What happens when you search `WHERE NAME LIKE '%\'%'` ? How about `WHERE NAME LIKE '%Smith'` ? Does Mr. Smith's name pop out in any of those cases?  NOTE: I'm not suggesting you use that kind of search in production, but rather just to make sure you know how your apostrophes in names are stored. These Irish style names are a notorious pain in the neck to get right. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Ollie. That got me much closer to getting the correct results. I think all I need now is some time to tinker with this application and I'll be able to get it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

OP here (different account... not at work). I have access to the database through PHPMyAdmin, so I can see all the rows in the tables. Since I'm not at work right now I can't try your suggestion, but I will later. Thanks for the suggestions though!